# Registry change to set screen resolution

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

Where in the Registry does Windows keep the screen resolution? I found this, but I'm not sure if it's relevant:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{1A3EB677-F210-43AE-85B9-C6964FF59BF6}\0000]
"HighResBootCompatible"=dword:00000000
"InstalledDisplayDrivers"=hex(7):76,00,67,00,61,00,00,00,66,00,72,00,61,00,6d,\
  00,65,00,62,00,75,00,66,00,00,00,76,00,67,00,61,00,32,00,35,00,36,00,00,00,\
  76,00,67,00,61,00,36,00,34,00,6b,00,00,00,00,00
"VgaCompatible"=dword:00000001
"Device Description"="Standard VGA Graphics Adapter"
"HardwareInformation.ChipType"=hex:41,00,54,00,49,00,20,00,45,00,53,00,31,00,\
  30,00,30,00,30,00,00,00
"HardwareInformation.AdapterString"=hex:56,00,47,00,41,00,00,00
"HardwareInformation.DacType"=hex:38,00,20,00,62,00,69,00,74,00,00,00
"HardwareInformation.BiosString"=hex:30,00,31,00,2e,00,30,00,30,00,00,00
"HardwareInformation.MemorySize"=hex:00,00,00,01
```

Comment: Found it using google....http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-7-changes-screen-resolution-on-boot-up/13c17468-0d70-4827-a559-dca0fa558a69?auth=1

Comment: @Moab Thaks for your help but it does not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it here

http://windows7themes.net/en-us/how-to-change-screen-resolution-in-windows-7-via-shortcut-or-registry/

or

*Start---->Run--->regedit*

**Open:**

> My
>   Computer--->HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG--->System--->CurrentControlSet--->Control--->VIDEO--->(expand
>   all until you see 'Monitor')

**Locate:**
Name Type Data

> DefaultSetting.XResolution REG_DWORD 0x00000400 (1024)
>
> DefaultSetting.YResolution REG_DWORD 0x00000300 (768)

Comment: Hmm, there is no VIDEO section on Windows 10 it seems.

Comment: I don't know why, but on my Windows 7 computer, it was HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Hardware Profiles/UnitedVideo/CONTROL/VIDEO .